# ImageAdd or ImageSubtract on interior / masked part of image

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

I'm making a little icon to be the default favicon in my website template. To do this I'm taking one of those dumb [little globe network icons](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/img/globe_mask.png) and merging it with the [v11 Mathematica spikey icon](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/img/spikey.png). The final product looks like this:

[image: asd]

At favicon size it's not really noticeable, but it's fun anyway.

The way I'm doing this is by taking the spikey image and the globe image:

```
spikey =
  CloudImport[
CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/img/spikey.png"]];
baseIcon =
  CloudImport[

CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/img/globe_mask.png"]
   ];
```

And then merging the `spikey` [`AlphaChannel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AlphaChannel.html) with the `baseIcon` and then dilating the whole mess:

```
baseMask =
  With[{
    chan = AlphaChannel[spikey],
    ppos = PixelValuePositions[AlphaChannel[spikey], White]
    },
   ReplacePixelValue[
    chan,
    Thread[
     ppos ->
      PixelValue[baseIcon, ppos]
     ]
    ]
   ];
mask = Dilation[newMask, 1]
```

[image: mask]

before finally setting that as the `spikey` alpha channel:

```
newImg = SetAlphaChannel[spikey, mask]
```

The problem is this is a rather slow process. `PixelValuePositions` is slow and can be finnicky and `ReplacePixelValue` is slow, too (and honestly even `PixelValue` can be).

So I'd rather do this with [`ImageAdd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdd.html) and [`ImageSubtract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSubtract.html).

Unfortunately, neither of these really reproduce what I want when I use them by default.

Is there a good way to do this? I.e. apply an `ImageAdd`/`ImageSubtract` only to a masked part of an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that?

```
With[{alpha = AlphaChannel[spikey]}
, Dilation[
    ImageAdd[
      ImageMultiply[baseIcon, alpha ]
    , EdgeDetect @ alpha 
    ]
  , 1
  ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I knew it should have been super easy.